Magento\Framework\Exception\BulkException: One or more input exceptions have occurred while processing bulk
I'm in the process of setting up a new store and I'm getting 100's of these errors every hour.
The main error is:
Magento\Framework\Exception\BulkException: One or more input exceptions have occurred while processing bulk. in /var/www/vhosts/firesupport.uk/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-data-exporter/Plugin/MviewUpdatePlugin.php:68 Stack trace:

This appears to me to be a core Magento file which is throwing the error.
The full stack trace is here:
Magento\Framework\Exception\BulkException: One or more input exceptions have occurred while processing bulk. in vendor/magento/module-data-exporter/Plugin/MviewUpdatePlugin.php:68 Stack trace: 
#0 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\DataExporter\Plugin\MviewUpdatePlugin->aroundUpdate(Object(Magento\Framework\Mview\Processor\Interceptor), Object(Closure), 'indexer') 
#1 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\Mview\Processor\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('indexer') 
#2 generated/code/Magento/Framework/Mview/Processor/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\Mview\Processor\Interceptor->___callPlugins('update', Array, NULL) 
#3 vendor/magento/module-indexer/Model/Processor.php(119): Magento\Framework\Mview\Processor\Interceptor->update('indexer') 
#4 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor->updateMview() 
#5 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor\Interceptor->___callParent('updateMview', Array) 
#6 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() 
#7 generated/code/Magento/Indexer/Model/Processor/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor\Interceptor->___callPlugins('updateMview', Array, Array) 
#8 vendor/magento/module-indexer/Cron/UpdateMview.php(31): Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor\Interceptor->updateMview() 
#9 [internal function]: Magento\Indexer\Cron\UpdateMview->execute(Object(Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule)) 
#10 vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(368): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#11 vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(879): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->_runJob(1718643840, 1718643843, Array, Object(Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule), 'index') 
#12 vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(840): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->tryRunJob(1718643840, 1718643843, Array, Object(Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule), 'index') 
#13 vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php(280): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->processPendingJobs('index', Array, 1718643843) 
#14 vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) 
#15 vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(74): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) 
#16 vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(65): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer)) 
#17 generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('default', Array) 
#18 vendor/magento/framework/App/Cron.php(86): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('default') 
#19 vendor/magento/module-cron/Console/Command/CronCommand.php(126): Magento\Framework\App\Cron->launch() 
#20 vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(298): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) 
#21 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) 
#22 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand\Interceptor->___callParent('run', Array) 
#23 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) 
#24 generated/code/Magento/Cron/Console/Command/CronCommand/Interceptor.php(77): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand\Interceptor->___callPlugins('run', Array, Array) 
#25 vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1040): Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand\Interceptor->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) 
#26 vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(301): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Cron\Console\Command\CronCommand\Interceptor), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) 
#27 vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) 
#28 vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(171): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) 
#29 bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() 
#30 {main}

I've seen a similar question but that was related to a 3rd party module and I don't think this is a 3rd party module issue. Does anyone have any suggestions what I can do?
I'm getting the same issue on 2 versions running:
Magento 2.4.6
Magento 2.4.7
Any help is much appreciated.

This issue requires debugging to find its cause.

Have you fixed this?
What was the solution please.

I have also installed Magento 2.4.7 and encountering the same issue
CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\BulkException: One or more input exceptions have occurred while processing bulk. in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-data-exporter/Plugin/MviewUpdatePlugin.php:68 Any solution please let me know. Thanks

Yes. It is not related to any third-party extensions.
Need to debug at the Cron level. Need to check the Cron one by one for the same.
